# Presentations of smooth manifolds

Tags: abelian-groups, duality-theorems, classifying-spaces, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

A presentation of a affine complex variety consists of finitely many polynomials $f_1,...,f_m$ in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]$. A presentation of a projective complex variety consists of finitely many homogeneous polynomials $f_1,...,f_m$ in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_{n}]$.

Is there something similar for smooth manifolds and power series? Specifically, I would like to figure out how to think about "presentations" for smooth manifolds using power series.

What is a notion of presentation for smooth manifolds and their bundles?

Comment: Every smooth manifold has a (unique) real-analytic structure. Maybe this is what you wanted to know. If you assume tameness, then every smooth manifold is isomorphic to a smooth real-algebraic subset of $R^N$ for some $N$.